# Swift: convert from two arrays to dataset for using in charts

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dataset

I have two double arrays:

```
x = [(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]
y = [(3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0)]
```

I want to use these variables `x` and `y` in this code line (instead fixed values):

```
(chartPoints: [(2.0, 2.6),....], color: UIColor.redColor())
```

How can I combine them so that I have something of type `[(Double, Double)]`?

Comment: I am sorry. But I am confused with this part - I want use this values instead the given values in chartbar coordinates. Could you please elaborate your question?

Comment: im using the swiftcharts framework for xcode to display a chart, this code line is needed. These values can you give as double values.
But i want to pass two arrays, one for x and one for y coordinates

Comment: `[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)]` would be an array with a single tuple element. Is that really what you have, or is it `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As @Hamish suggested you can simply do:**

```
let pointArr = Array(zip(x, y))
```

**Or you can do this:**

Given the double Arrays:

```
x : [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
y : [Double] = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]
```

To combine these into an array of `(Double, Double)`, you'd do this:

```
let x : [Double] = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]
let y : [Double] = [3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0]

var pointArr : [(Double, Double)] = [] // Empty array of points that you'll fill below

for index in 0..<x.count { // for all x values
    if index < y.count { // make sure that there aren't more x values than y values
        let newPoint = (x[index], y[index]) // Create a new point
        pointArr.append(newPoint) // Add the point to the array
    }
}
```

And then to use it:

```
(chartPoints: pointArr, color: UIColor.redColor())
```

Comment: thanks, but i get the error: "Cannot convert value of type [CGPoint] to expected element type Array(Double, Double)"

Comment: Ok see edits. I fixed it.

Comment: Or just `Array(zip(x, y))`

Comment: @Hamish, noted and updated

Comment: thats it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but can create an array of `CGPoint`s:

```
let a: Array<CGFloat> = [1, 2, 3]
let b: Array<CGFloat> = [6, 7, 8]
var c = Array<CGPoint>()

for i in 0..<a.count {
    if i < b.count {
        c.append(CGPointMake(a[i], b[i]))
    }
}
```